# Error: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with this since it's showing and I tried with global variable etc an issue remains..

```
var $ = jQuery;
var $window    = $(window),
        $moving1   = $(".scroller1"),
        $holder1   = $("#scroller-wrap1"),      
        offset1;

$window.load(function() {       
        offset1     = $holder1.offset();
});

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset1.top) {
        $moving1.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $moving1.removeClass('fixed');
    }
    if ($window.scrollTop() > (offset1.top + $holder1.height() - $moving1.height() - 60)) {
        $moving1.removeClass('fixed', 1000);
    }

    //console.log("scroll: " +$window.scrollTop());
});
```

Basically I am checking if the windows if fully loaded so I can make the calculations without error but I guess it's not correct.

This is inside wordpress that's why I need the jQuery part.

Comment: What is the problem that is happening? please, clarify your question

Comment: @CalvinNunesI get "Error: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" on Console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. The error is coming from this command:

```
if ($window.scrollTop() > offset1.top) {
```

and it means that `offset1` is `undefined`.  Now, you are initializing `offset1` in your `.load` event, but you are setting it equal to `$holder` and `$holder1` is initialized before the document is ready, so it becomes `undefinded`.

Your code can be reduced greatly by just adding a **[`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)** function. You also don't have to do this `var $ = JQuery` as that is automatic.:

```js
// Passing a function to JQuery creates a "document.ready()" callback
// function that will automatically be executed when the DOM is built.
$(function(){

  var $window    = $(window);
  var $moving1   = $(".scroller1");
  var $holder1   = $("#scroller-wrap1");
  var offset1 =  $holder1.offset();

  // JQuery recommends the use of the .on() function to bind 
  // event callbacks as opposed to event methods.
  $window.on("scroll", function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset1.top) {
        $moving1.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $moving1.removeClass('fixed');
    }
    
    if ($window.scrollTop() > (offset1.top + $holder1.height() - $moving1.height() - 60)) {
        $moving1.removeClass('fixed', 1000);
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need the jQuery part because I'm using it inside a Theme Options = Wordpress custom theme

Comment: @FilipeOS OK, if you say so. But, you still have to address the main points in my answer.